# Create matrix from predefined cells

Tags: vba, excel, matrix

Good afternoon,

I'm quite new to VBA and Excel and i'm having the following problem.
I have a function that requires a symmetric matrix as input to calculate the eigenvalue `[=MEigenvalueMax (A1: C3)]`. However, I have the data for the matrix in different cells. My question is therefore whether there is a function with which I can define predefined cells as a matrix, e. g. `=MEigenvalMax ({A1, A2, A3; B1, B2, B3; C1, C2, C3})`.
Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Use VBA to reposition (copy) the cells as you want them to be.

Comment: Thanks! Is there another way where you can avoid copying all the cells?

Comment: Yes, write a VBA function

Answer (score 0):

to fill an array with range values you simply go like follows:

```
Dim eigenvalueMatrix As Variant

eigenvalueMatrix = Range("A1:C3").Value
```